# Perl modifying hash reference in subroutine

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

I am having trouble understanding the hash references and changing the hash in place, instead of returning it. I want to write a sub routine which will return a value from hash and also modify the hash. I was facing some issues while coding for it. So, I wrote the following basic code to understand modifying the hash in place.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#Check hash and array references
#Author: Sidartha Karna
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

sub checkHashRef{
   my ($hashRef, $arrVal) = @_;
   my %hashDeref = %{$hashRef};

   $hashDeref{'check'} = 2;           
   push(@{$arrVal}, 3);

   print "There:" ;
   print Dumper $hashRef;      
   print Dumper %hashDeref;           
   print Dumper $arrVal

}


my %hashVal = ('check', 1);
my @arrVal = (1, 2);

checkHashRef(\%hashVal, \@arrVal);

print "here\n";
print Dumper %hashVal;
print Dumper @arrVal;
```

The output observed is:

```
    There:$VAR1 = {
          'check' => 1
        };
    $VAR1 = 'check';
    $VAR2 = 2;
    $VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ];
    here
    $VAR1 = 'check';
    $VAR2 = 1;
    $VAR1 = 1;
    $VAR2 = 2;
    $VAR3 = 3;
```

From the output, I inferred that, changes to hashDeref are not modifying the data in the reference. Is my understanding correct? Is there a way to modify the hash variable in place instead of returning it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is making a (shallow) copy of `%hashVal`:

```
my %hashDeref = %{$hashRef};
```

The hash-ref `$hashRef` still points to `%hashVal` but `%hashDeref` doesn't, it is just a copy. If you want to modify the passed hash-ref in-place, then work with the passed hash-ref:

```
sub checkHashRef{
   my ($hashRef, $arrVal) = @_;
   $hashRef->{'check'} = 2;
   #...
```

That will leave your changes in `%hashVal`. In the array case, you never make a copy, you just dereference it in-place:

```
push(@{$arrVal}, 3);
```

and the change to `$arrVal` shows up in `@arrVal`.